# You roll 3 dices with 6 sides each - Three "0", Two "1" and One "2" - what are the percentages of each (0-6) result?

Tags: dice

I'm making a game based on Dice Rolls, and I need some percentages based on the results of these rolls.

The situation: 
You roll 3 dice and get points based on the results. 
Each die has 6 sides - Three "0", Two "1" and One "2".

The Problem: 
Since you can get results that vary from 0-6, I need the chances of getting each one.

---

What I did and what I need:

Result 0: (0,0,0) - 1/8 or 12,5%

Result 1:

Result 2:

Result 3:

Result 4:

Result 5:

Result 6: (2,2,2) - 1/216 or 0,46%

---

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, 3 dices, sorry, will edit that!

Comment: A cheater like me just has Wolfram alpha expand $(3+2x+x^2)^3$. :)

Comment: By the way- "dices" is a verb meaning to cut something into small cubes.  "Dice", as a noun, is already plural- it is the plural of the singular noun "die".

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This really just shows the answer, not really a "why."
Wolfram alpha says:

$$(3+2x+x^2)^3=x^6+6 x^5+21 x^4+44 x^3+63 x^2+54 x+27$$

So your probabilities are: 
$$\begin{align}
P(0)&=\frac{27}{216}=\frac{1}8\\
P(1)&=\frac{54}{216}=\frac{1}{4}\\
P(2)&=\frac{63}{216}=\frac{7}{24}\\
P(3)&=\frac{44}{216}=\frac{11}{54}\\
P(4)&=\frac{21}{216}=\frac{7}{72}\\
P(5)&=\frac{6}{216}=\frac{1}{36}\\
P(6)&=\frac{1}{216}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yay! Thank you! I will read more on that for sure.